# JSSOR How Copy&Paste a complete layer from one slide to the next

Tags: jssor

I have a Text+Html layer on the 1st slide that has a complicated set of transitions.

I need these same transitions on each slide - with just the text changed.

Can I Copy&Paste it somehow from slide to slide, to save re-creating it (with the psssibility or error)

Thanks

PS - VERY impressed with JSSOR

Answer (score 1):

With `copy/paste`, it will create new layer from old one, just like making a new layer all by yourself.

You can copy one or more layers, and paste it into any other slide.

Also, you can export one or more layers, and import it at anywhere. Thus you can import layers from another slider.

Comment: Excellent - both techniques work fine - thanks.
I had seen Import/export but hadn't inspected what it did,
and I hadn't found copy/paste - which I now see is under the right button.